# Laravel eloquent relationship return empty array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to show one link, one page, one tag, and many comments with user name from "users", but, the comments return one empty array. All tables have "id" as primary key and auto increment.

**Controller:**

```
$link = Link::with('page', 'tag', 'comments.user')->where('friendly_url', $id)->first();
return view('site.link', compact('link'));
```

**Model (link)**

```
class Link extends Model
{
public function page()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Page::class);
}

public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tag::class);
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}   
}
```

**Model (comments)**

```
class Comment extends Model
{

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    }
```

**View:**

```
    @foreach($link->comments as $comment)
    <li class="comment">
    <h1>{{ $comment->user->name . $comment->user->lastname }}</h1>
   <h2>{{ $comment->content }}</h2>
    @endforeach



dd($link);

0 => Link {#291 ▼
      #relations: array:3 [▼
        "page" => Page {#295 ▶}
        "tag" => Tag {#289 ▶}
        "comments" => Collection {#292 ▼
          #items: array:2 [▼
            0 => Comment {#299 ▶}
            1 => Comment {#301 ▶}
          ]
        }
      ]
```

SOLVED:

```
$link->getRelation('comments');
```

But I want to show the userProfile too, but return 0...

**CONTROLLER:**

```
$link = Link::where('friendly_url', $id)->with('page', 'tag', 'comments.user', 'comments.userProfile')->first();

        dd($link);



#relations: array:3 [▼
"page" => Page {#296 ▶}
"tag" => Tag {#290 ▶}
"comments" => Collection {#293 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Comment {#300 ▶}
    1 => Comment {#302 ▼
      #relations: array:2 [▼
        "user" => User {#305 ▶}
        "userProfile" => null
      ]
```

Comment: Do you have `link_id` and `user_id` in the `comments` table? Have you tried to do `Link::with('page', 'tag', 'comments', 'comments.user')`?

Comment: What exactly is `$id` in your `->where` clause?

Comment: Yes, the table have the two fields... $id = 'cars-more-expensive-in-2017' (friendly url)... Yes I tried this way too...

Comment: I edit the post with the result in DD, look there, the comments were obtained...

Comment: 0 => Link {#291 ▼ #relations: array:3 [▼ "page" => Page {#295 ▶} "tag" => Tag {#289 ▶} "comments" => Collection {#292 ▼ #items: array:2 [▼ 0 => Comment {#299 ▶} 1 => Comment {#301 ▶} ] } ]

Comment: try `dd($link['comments'])`

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso so, there are comments there. Then `dd($link->comments)` should return a collection of two comments and not `[]`

Comment: Return the comments, but in the view, the array "@foreach($link->comments as $comment)" is empty...

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for $link->comments

Comment: SOLVED, THANK YOU...

Answer (score 0):

1, Database: You must have `link_id` and `user_id` in the comments table

2, `Controller` : You should use `with()` function to get `comments` and `user`

```
    $link = Link::with(['page', 'tag', 'comments' => function($query){
           $query->with('user')
    }])->where('friendly_url', $id)->first();

    return view('site.link', compact('link'));
```

You can use `dd($link)` to check relationship data

You can try them. 
You can comment below for me to support you

Comment: Link {#291 ▼
  #relations: array:3 [▼
    "page" => Page {#295 ▶}
    "tag" => Tag {#289 ▶}
    "comments" => Collection {#292 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Comment {#299 ▶}
        1 => Comment {#301 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]

Comment: Return the comments, but in the view, the array "@foreach($link->comments as $comment)" is empty...

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for $link->comments

Comment: Can you dd($link->comments) ?

Comment: dd($link->page) return Page {#295 ▼
  #table: "pages"
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"

Comment: "comments" => Collection {#292 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Comment {#299 ▶}
        1 => Comment {#301 ▶}
      ] What is collection?

Comment: In the view have @foreach($link->comments as $comment)

Comment: Where? return view('site.link', compact('link'));

Comment: return view('site.link')->with('link', $link); but the $link->comments return 0...

Comment: You should `with()`  `comments` instead of `comments.user`

Comment: Now, I want  to show the table users_profile with users in comments, but the userProfile return empty...  #relations: array:2 [▼
            "user" => User {#305 ▶}
            "userProfile" => null
          ]

Comment: congratulations @ValterSousaCardoso